# How to create iOS NWConnection for TLS with self signed cert?

Tags: ios, ssl, ios12

I'm trying to use Apple's new NWConnection class for my MQTT client. For testing, I need to be able to create a TLS connection to my local test broker, which has a self signed cert.

So far, I'm just setting up the connection using:

```
self.connection = NWConnection(host: NWEndpoint.Host("172.16.202.172"), port: NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: 8899), using: .tls)
```

But when I connect, I get the following spewage on my console:

```
2019-01-30 17:05:51.010580-0800 myAp[2591:608137] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]
2019-01-30 17:05:57.939157-0800 myApp[2591:608135] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_alert_callback_handler(3724) [C5:1][0x103e087d0] Alert level: fatal, description: certificate unknown
2019-01-30 17:05:57.939382-0800 myApp[2591:608135] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_error_print(3676) boringssl ctx 0x282226af0: 4360838776:error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.230.1/ssl/handshake.cc:360:
2019-01-30 17:05:57.939510-0800 myApp[2591:608135] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_get_error_code(3560) [C5:1][0x103e087d0] SSL_AD_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN
```

In the past, when I've used `URLSession.shared.dataTask` to download a file from an nginx https server, I've added the following to my info.plist

```
<dict>
    <key>App Transport Security Settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>172.16.202.172</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionsAllowsInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

But that doesn't seem to have done the trick in this case. When I click on Apple's documentation links for things like `NWParameter` to pass in place of the stock `.tls`, thinking I could tune the xls settings, there's just no info in the Apple docs.

So what is the right way to create a `NWConnection` for TLS communication using self signed certs?

Comment: I don't believe that you can use an IP address as an exception domain; you can only use a domain name.  You will probably have to disable ATS entirely.   Can you just not use TLS for your test broker?

Comment: I can give my test server a local dns name and rebuild the certs with that and try that. I'll try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the complete/best answer, but I found this approach on the Apple Developer forums:

```
func createTLSParameters(allowInsecure: Bool, queue: DispatchQueue) -> NWParameters {
    let options = NWProtocolTLS.Options()
    sec_protocol_options_set_verify_block(options.securityProtocolOptions, { (sec_protocol_metadata, sec_trust, sec_protocol_verify_complete) in
        let trust = sec_trust_copy_ref(sec_trust).takeRetainedValue()
        var error: CFError?
        if SecTrustEvaluateWithError(trust, &error) {
            sec_protocol_verify_complete(true)
        } else {
            if allowInsecure == true {
                sec_protocol_verify_complete(true)
            } else {
                sec_protocol_verify_complete(false)
            }
        }
    }, queue)
    return NWParameters(tls: options)
}

self.workQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "mqtt")
self.connection = NWConnection(
    host: NWEndpoint.Host("172.16.202.172"),
    port: NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: 8899),
    using: createTLSParameters(allowInsecure: true, queue: self.workQueue))
```

Using this technique, I didn't need the info.plist change at all.

There's some indication on said forum that it is preferrable to pull the self signed cert into your iOS box somehow.